# iterate through array (recieved via json) to get values

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I'm trying to get the IDs of the steam groups someone is connected to. Here is the json output:

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": true,
        "groups": [
            {
                "gid": "111"
            },
            {
                "gid": "222"
            },
            {
                "gid": "333"
            },
            {
                "gid": "444"
            },
            {
                "gid": "555"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

I've attempted it via:

```
$groupIDs = $reply['response']['groups'];
foreach ($groupIDs as $gID) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

I'm getting the following error, but I'm struggling to see how to correct it.

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

---

Sorry I didn't make it clear. I'm already decoding it before the foreach().

```
    $reply = json_decode($reply, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to decode the json string using php function json_decode. Then iterate the object as shown below

```
$string = '{
    "response": {
        "success": true,
        "groups": [
            {
                "gid": "111"
            },
            {
                "gid": "222"
            },
            {
                "gid": "333"
            },
            {
                "gid": "444"
            },
            {
                "gid": "555"
            }
        ]

    }
}';
$array = json_decode($string);

foreach($array->response->groups as $value ){
    echo $value->gid;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php

Try:

```
$response = json_decode($reply, true);
$groupIDs = $response['response']['groups'];
foreach ($groupIDs as $gID) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: What about `"gid"`?? `$gID` sounds like you have them already!

Answer (score 0):

use json_decode($response) [cf doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php)

```
$rep = json_decode($response)
foreach ($rep->response->groups as $gID) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$groups = $reply['response']->groups;
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    print $group->gid;
}
```

In json each `{}` means is parsed as object, each `[]` is parsed as array.